# Precedence constraints in Permutations

Tags: matlab

I am doing my work on archeology domain, I am trying to generate all the sequence of a given variable with some precedence constraint. For example, if we have five object `1 2 3 4 5` , then there are `5!` ways but if we impose some precedence constraints like:

- The sequence should always start from 1.
- After 1 only 2 or 3 can be attached.
- 4 can come after 5 or 3
- 5 can come after 4 or 2

at last I should get answer like given below

```
1 2 3 5 4; 1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 5 4 3; 1 2 5 3 4; 
1 3 4 5 2; 1 3 4 2 5; 1 3 2 5 4; 1 3 2 4 5;
```

I tried different function like allcomb, ndgrid, treenode, perms, and matrix fuction but I can't able to impose the precedence constraints. And also I am using MATLAB for first time but i searched all question and answer but haven't found the one I am looking for.

I found some answer without OR constraints but in my problem i have to use OR.

Comment: 1 2 3 5 4 is not valid because 5 cannot come after 3, same for 1 3 2 4 5 because 4 can come after 5 or 3, not 2...

Comment: @aka.nice thank you for editing :)  but I need these two sequence also although 5 can't come after 3 but in that sequence 2 is already there so we can add 5.                                                                                                I think permutation will not allow us to do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest generating all possible combinations of 1 to 5, and remove the invalid ones.

Code example:

```
%generates all possible combinations from 1 to 5, where 1 is the first
%number
allCombs = perms(2:5);
allCombs = [ones(size(allCombs,1),1),allCombs];

%calclates rows in which the constraints for 1,4,5 holds
constraintsFor1 = union(findKAfterNRows(allCombs,2,1),findKAfterNRows(allCombs,3,1));
constraintsFor4 = union(findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 4,5 ),findKAfterNRows(     allCombs, 4,3 ));
constraintsFor5 = union(findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 5,2 ),findKAfterNRows( allCombs, 5,4 ));

%calculates the valid rows
resultRows = intersect(constraintsFor1,constraintsFor4);
resultRows = intersect(resultRows,constraintsFor5);

%generates final output
outputMask = allCombs(resultRows,:);
```

Where findKAfterNRows is a function which receive a matrix of combinations, and two numbers - k and n, and returns rows in which k comes after n:

```
function [ validRows ] = findKAfterNRows( mat, k,n )
kMask = single(mat==k);
nMask = single(mat==n);
n = size(mat,2);
kernel = zeros(1,n);
kernel(1:floor(n/2)) = 1;
kMaskShiftLeft = conv2(kMask,kernel,'same');
validRows = find(sum(nMask==1 & kMaskShiftLeft==1,2)==1);
end
```

Results:

```
outputMask =

 1     3     4     2     5
 1     3     4     5     2
 1     3     2     4     5
 1     3     2     5     4
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     2     3     5     4
 1     2     5     4     3
 1     2     5     3     4
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for answer. But I need that other two sequences also in my answer because although 4 can come after 5 or 3 but the code should check all the number of that particular sequences.          for example:-  I want  1 2 3 5 4 , because 5 can come after 2 or 4 only but in the given case 2 is already in the sequence so it is possible to add 5 after 3 in this case.    And sorry for my English I put my question wrong. I hope now you understand.

Comment: I understand now. I updated my answer accordingly, and now it works according to what you described. let me know if you have any more questions or comments.

Comment: oops i was solving the problem but i found it is not possible to get for more then 10 components, my computer getting hang and after searching through internet i found its not possible to have permutation for more then 11 components :(. Is  there any other way to do the same?????

Comment: That's a totally different question, I suggest posting another question in stack overflow about it. good luck!

Comment: Since one digit is always known (the first element being `1`), I'd actually just use `perms(1:4)`, prepend `1` to all of them and search those for the other criteria. The more known coefficients, the less computing power is required.

Comment: @drorco I have problem with the code can you please see my answer of this question where i post my code, thank you